# How can I truncate 0s from the end of numbers?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I've written a C application that reverses the digits the user has input into the application.

---

Actual input:`420`

Actual output: `024`

---

However, I'm looking to truncate 0 from the end of the number, if it exists.

---

Input:`420`

Expected output: `24`

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void) {
 int x, s;
 scanf("%i",&x);

 for(int i = x; i > 0; ){
   s = i % 10;
   printf("%i", s); 
   i = i / 10;
    }

   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You need a variable called `non_zero_digit_found`. Initially, that variable should be false. When you find a non-zero digit, set the variable to true. Only print digits when the variable is true. Note that if the user enters `0` as the number, the loop will end with the variable still false, and no digits will have been printed. That special case needs to be handled.

Comment: @codeloverfromkz You are explicitly outputting zeroes printf("%i", s);

Comment: codeloverfromkz, with input 0123, what output is expected?

Comment: With input `"0"`, what ouput is expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can to this way, until you don't find the first non-zero number don't print.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int x, s;
  scanf("%i",&x);

  int first = 1;

  for(int i = x; i > 0; ){
    s = i % 10;

    if (first && s == 0){
      i = i / 10;
      if (i % 10 != 0)
        first = 0;
      continue;
    }

    printf("%i", s); 
    i = i / 10;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this for loop

```
 for(int i = x; i > 0; ){
   s = i % 10;
   printf("%i", s); 
   i = i / 10;
    }
```

you are explicitly outputs zeroes if `s` is equal to `0`.

Also if `x` is initially equal to `0` then nothing is outputted.

And if the entered number is negative then again nothing will be outputted that will confuse the user of the program.

One of approaches it to build a new number based on the entered number. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int Base = 10;
    
    int x = 0;
    scanf( "%i", &x );
    
    long long int reverse = 0;
    
    do
    {
        reverse = Base * reverse + x % Base;
    } while ( x /= Base );
    
    printf( "%lld\n", reverse );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
-123456789
```

then the output will be

```
-987654321
```